# Disk Management

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

1. When I use Synaptic Package Manager, most of the time I am getting message that there is no space and update aborts
2. I have full userspace available 145 GB NTFS partition which is totally free - how to use the same for software installations and updates?
3. How to move some of the installation to the same partition, if they are not installed in that partition
4. It is taking too much time to bring the first desktop after logging in

I am using 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr..

Comment: Is it feasible to reformat the 145 Gb partition to ext4? This will give you more possibilities than NTFS.

Comment: I have already deleted that partition of 145 GB and created a new partition - how to extend the same to root is not clear to me and there is no option of extend in gparted

Comment: The basic procedure is as follows: you use a `sudo mount` command to attach a partition, say /dev/sdb1, to a location in your directory tree, say `/mnt/bigdisk`. Once that works, you add a line to your `/etc/fstab` file to auto-mount the partition at the next reboot.

Comment: Did - additional partition is mounted after reboot, but it still shows that root has only 270~MB space!

Comment: If you use the `df` command to look at file system sizes, that is correct, as `df` reports only the space on the partition itself. `df` will now report that `/mnt/bigdisk` has 145Gb left. If you need to make room for updates, you need to move large files from the root partition to `/mnt/bigdisk`.

Comment: Could you go to `gparted` and post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You said "I have full userspace available 145 GB NTFS partition which is totally free" . So you can convert that partition into EXT4( No direct way , you have to delete that and then convert into ext4) . You can use Gparted.

[Terminal method of formatting storage drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517354/terminal-method-of-formatting-storage-drive)