# How do I create an Ubuntu partition on my hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have the following partitions when I run `lsblk` in a terminal:

[image]

How can I use the 500G size `vdb` area?

How can I check if `vdb` already has a partition or if I need to create a new one?

Comment: On a command line `parted -l` lists your partitions and formatting. To create a new file system see https://askubuntu.com/questions/517354/terminal-method-of-formatting-storage-drive

Comment: The easiest way to view and edit parittions on your disks might be to boot into the Ubuntu installer (from a live DVD or USB stick). Then use the visual partitioning tool within the installer.

Comment: parted -l returns Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  53.7GB  53.7GB  primary  ext3         boot

Answer (score 0):

I also did what  Nick Weinberg was mentioning. It just worked fine for me and able to partition 4TB disk using Gparted application from installer DVD.

OS: Live Mint 17.3 ROSA

Comment: Please consider improve your answer including links and context. askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer