# Ubuntu will only run from the live disk and not install my hard disk is corrupted

Tags: hard-drive

Ubuntu loads from the live CD but after going through the install it requires me to put the live boot in I did a complete erase and install with Ubuntu 16 is there anyway I can use terminal to format the hard drive and start again I do know it probably has some corrupt areas, I even tried loaded from CD of Windows XP but the drive wont read it but at least I get a working desktop with the Ubuntu 6 version Can any guru's out there give me the script to type in exactly and see if I can get this PC up and running again if not it's probably trashed completely thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot live Ubuntu, then you should use **GParted** , a free partition editor.
First, unmount your hard disk (right click -> Unmount). Then you will see *Format to* and choose *ntfs* file system. Apply the changes and that´s it.

Also, [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/517365/567386) is answer about formatting from terminal. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Don´t forget to make backup!

Comment: Dear @se0D2 I did all you suggested and am extremely grateful for your assistance, sadly I have to give that Asus hard drive a burial with full military honors, There is no helping it he's shuffled off this mortal coil, He's Carked it etc... So While I did not have anything useful on that machine it lives with it's live boot CD in the optical drive and is attached to my large idiot box with a HDMI cable  and now plays silly You tube videos and TED Talks I've subscribed to on the big screen in my lounge room.  While I'm not a hoarder I find it difficult to toss the old beastie out,  Cheers Lou