# Format second hard drive to prepare it for Windows installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hard-drive

I was dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 when Windows tried to do the Creator's Update and went horribly wrong. It went so wrong that I can't even completely reinstall it with my original Windows 7 DVD. I'm hoping that I can use Ubuntu to format that hard drive which will allow me to put Windows 7 back on it with the DVD. I've seen great information about how to format drives with Ubuntu (for example, [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517354/terminal-method-of-formatting-storage-drive)), but I can't figure out how best to format a drive in Ubuntu to prepare it for a Windows installation. What is the best way to format a drive so that I can put Windows on it? Should I delete my extra partitions? Or does it not matter? Note that it doesn't have to be from the terminal (GParted would be fine).

Comment: Why would you reinstall a Windows 10 with a Windows 7 DVD? You can download the ISO from Microsoft, make a USB with their tool and install with that. IF you machine is UEFI than by all means install in that mode, it doesn't even matter if you reinstall Ubuntu first. The UEFI mode avoids the "horribly wrong" problem.

Comment: I tried it via a USB but kept running into errors, as detailed [here] (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/windows-10-is-not-entering-automatic-repair-mode/b703f2f3-4ac4-4b4d-8be9-3341dd78f24c)