# How to Extend Ubuntu 18.04 Manually Configured Disk?

Tags: server, 18.04, disk, fdisk, disk-management

I have Ubuntu 18.04 server, I have 30 GB of space on my ext4 type manual disk, I want to add another 20 gb. How can I achieve this?

[image: picture of the teminal output for df -h]

I did not add a separate disk, I expanded the existing disk.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** Please don't post text as pictures, but copy-paste the text instead so we can copy-paste and search too! Also, use the `{}` button in the toolbar to format it as text as well. *Thank you for helping us help you!* **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

the tool you're looking for is [`resize2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs)

Or alternatively [`parted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/parted.8.html)

check this answer out : https://askubuntu.com/a/517365/307184
you'll have to use it's subcommand `resizepart` passing it the arguments `partitionnumber` and `endpoint`

Comment: Could you please show me a few examples?

Comment: follow my link. also do you have a desktop environement on your ubnutu? your screenshot leads me to believe you're in command-prompt only. if you have a desktop environement than you don't need parted, you can use gparted.

Comment: thank you. resize2fs was last used.