# Is there a way to run a auto batch command that when Ubuntu starts up it runs it?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, format

1. I need to view had drive serial number gigs etc also computer hardware info( CPU ram etc) like a system profile.
2. I also need to auto wipe hard drive( doesn't need to have a partition)when done.

I work with laptops and get them in 100 to 200 at a time but wiping one by one takes to long.I want to just plug in a USB, boot to Ubuntu then it give me the info and then ask to wipe hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do all of that from the BIOS of a system so without the need to enter the operating system it holds.

> I want to just plug in a usb, boot to Ubuntu then it give me the info and then ask to wipe hard drive.

Also a possibility. Create a live session (with persistent storage if you want to create a script with commands) and you can use a couple of commands to get all you want.

These 3 will show lots of info...

```
sudo dmidecode --type bios
sudo dmidecode --type system
sudo dmidecode --type memory
```

You can also use  `>> /dir/persistent/storage/info.txt` behind each of the commands to store the info on the live session.

Formatting a disc is a command too. Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/517365/15811 for a couple of methods. One of them will be ...

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

This is an example; you need to change `/dev/sdb1` to the device that holds the unmounted partitions. It is likely it will be in `/media/` with a unique id (UUID) that changes per system so putting it into a script will be difficult (but not impossible).

You really do not want a partition formatted automatically when booting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a few things. The bios don't give full detail info, only the high end laptops with the newer bios. I deal with random laptops (HP,DELL, IBM, Mac's etc.) especially the MacBooks which doesn't have a Bios. This is why I need Ubuntu to display serial numbers and specs so data log them. I just want to boot into Ubuntu, don't have to  be the GUI just terminal and a script to auto run after 5 seconds of Boot-up. I need it to show hdd sized and serial, memory and cpu specs. basically a profile of the computer so I can log it.

Comment: I did some research and found very good program "neofetch" and "inxi -dxx" check them out to give you an ideo of what info im looking for. also I tried to make terminal auto run when Ubuntu start by going to the startup and add it but it doesn't work. I think I think I pointing to the wrong terminal. I cant really find where it is stored to select it. I went to usr/share/applications/ gnome.terminal something cant remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: This my be the reason It didn't run,might not be the right .app. After I added it, I then added to the command in terminal to auto-run "inxi -dxx && neofetch"