# Partitioning new HDD Ububtu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm formatting a new 1TB HDD with a single dos partition; `sdb1`.

Typing `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1`:

```
$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I have a single partition, no extended partitions.  I'm not sure what this message refers to.  I have tried a variety of suggestions without success.

Is there an error or does this refer only to (nonexistent) extended partitions?  Should I ignore this and continue and expand the space using `resize2fs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminal method of formatting storage drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517354/terminal-method-of-formatting-storage-drive) - The command you are using does not format hard drives or create partitions.

Comment: e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems, key word CHECK not create.

Answer (score 1):

To format a disk as `ext4` (the default for Ubuntu), you could do it like this:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

The `e2fsck` command [is used to check partitions for errors](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/e2fsck.8.html). As there is no valid partition to check, there is *technically* an error.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried to expand the fs space but got...   $ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: But trying your suggestion...   
mke2fs 1.44.1
Creating filesystem with 244190390 4k blocks and 61054976 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 0adb5d57-2325-40b1-8589-f92f70cf4ff4
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
 102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

Comment: then sudo fdisk --list...and there it is!     Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux